# How to make N .o files from N .c files using makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have 2 .c files that defined in the makefile:

```
SOURCES = main.c \
          memory.c
```

and I want to build 2 .o files using 1 command "make compile-all" (and don't link them), but can't understand how to do this.
I could create var for objective files and add .PHONY command:

```
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
.PHONY: compile-all
```

But what should be written next?
I guess it should be something similar with this:

```
%.o: %.c $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

But there's no way I can succeed.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why can't you succeed?  What happens when your try to build?

Comment: You actually don't even need that because make has built in rules that know how to compile a .c file into a .o file.  so, to repeat what Stephen said, what doesn't work?  When asking questions you should always include the command you typed and the result you got, and explain why it wasn't what you wanted, using cut and paste of exact text rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: Well, I mean, presumably you've defined the `compile-all` target even though you haven't shown it to us: `compile-all: $(OBJS)`

Comment: @StephenNewell
Thanks for the advice! Next time I will give more detailed information.
@MadScientist
Thank you,
`.PHONY: compile-all`
`compile-all: $(OBJS)`
`$(OBJS): $(SOURCES)`
`$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@`
works good for my purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BASENAME := main
TARGET := $(BASENAME).out
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

%.i: %.c
    $(CC) -E $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

%.asm: %.c
    $(CC) -S $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

.PHONY: build
build:$(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(PLATFORM_FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET) *.i *.asm $(BASENAME).map

.PHONY: compile-all
compile-all: $(OBJS)
```

`make compile-all` creates .o files from all .c files.